# bash - recursivly update files [solved]

Tags: bash, grep, find, exec, cp

From time to time I need to update several hundred files in sub-directories. I would like to automate the process.

I am able to find all files that I need to update using either of this commands.

```
find | grep "test.txt"
or
find ./ -name "test.txt"
```

Their output is identical...

```
./test.txt
./dir 4/test.txt
./dir 3/test.txt
./dir 2/test.txt
./dir 1/test.txt
./dir 1/dir 4/test.txt
./dir 1/dir 3/test.txt
./dir 1/dir 2/test.txt
./dir 1/dir 1/test.txt
```

In the past I would re-direct the output to a text file and manually edit each line...

```
cp newfile.txt ./test.txt
cp newfile.txt ./dir 4/test.txt
cp newfile.txt ./dir 3/test.txt
etc...
```

I assume (and have tried) I need to feed the above output to the cp or exec command in some way. How do I do that?
:-) Thx

---

@allan - I think you know what I need but I still am getting errors. I tried both your suggestions.

```
./cp-test.sh: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
./cp-test.sh: line 6: `done'


#! /usr/bin/bash

find ./ -name "test.txt" | while read f do
# cp "test.txt" $f
echo cp "test.txt" $f
done

# or example 2
 xargs -d '\n' -i echo cp "test.txt" \{\} < find ./ -name "test.txt"
 # xargs -d '\n' -i echo cp "test.txt" \{\} < `find ./ -name "test.txt"`
```

---

**Eventually this worked...**

```
find ./ -name "test.txt" | xargs -d '\n' -i cp "test.txt" \{\}
```

Comment: `replace them with a newer version`, how do you want to do that? renaming the files with specific string, prefix or suffix?

Comment: Before and after directory trees work well for this (defining “replace them with a newer version”)

Comment: If the file are identical update the first file and replace the rest with symlinks.

Comment: Please update question and clarify what you mean with "replace them with a newer version.".

Comment: BTW, you don't need find. Just turn on _globstar_ and do a `for f in **/test.txt`

Comment: Note that your _grep_ approach also locates a file named as foobar_test.txt, while `find` only returns files with that exact name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write a suitable loop:

```
find -name test.txt | while read f
do
  echo cp ... "$f"
done
```

You can also use a `<` with a command but then the pattern is:

```
while read f
do
  echo cp ... "$f"
done < <(find -name test.txt)
```

With xargs it would be:

```
find -name test.txt | xargs -d '\n' -i echo "cp ... '{}'"
```

Comment: @ allan - Thanks for the help.  I think you know what I need but I still am getting errors. I tried both your suggestions. see my comment and example  above.

Comment: Your script needs to start with '#!` (you only have `!`).  bash is usually installed in /usr/bin but those are merging so that might be fine.  The `<` requires a file, if you want to use find there just do a pipe: `find ... | while read ...`  Same idea with xargs: `find ... | xargs .`.`

Comment: Just a typo, Bash file has #. Still getting an error: ./cp-test.sh: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `done'

Comment: You need a newline or `;` before the `do` in your while loop (like my example shows).

Comment: Thanks, I tried these and it works. I like to add additional information to my scripts so I can later use them for reference. I think I solved this several years ago but seem to have lost my notes. I have over 300 scripts, take good notes, and try to ask only once!

Comment: Opps! I upvoted instead of checkmark two days ago, I'll fix that! :)